# Jenkins issue with marathon deployment plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, marathon, dcos

I've followed the https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/usage/tutorials/deploy-on-marathon/ guide for deploying an app from jenkins to marathon on dcos. I'm using a private registry hosted inside the dcos, and jenkins as well.

I'm getting the following output from jenkins console output,

> [Marathon] Failed to update Marathon application:
>
> [Marathon] Unauthorized (http status: 401)

any idea whats wrong?

I tried to create the app manually via marathon ui and it works fine.

Comment: Seems outdated to me, will notify our docs team. Try this one: https://github.com/dcos/examples/tree/master/1.8/jenkins

Comment: I had it wrong with the url, didn't use the 8080 port...

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas wanna put an answer?

Comment: since I don't have the whole picture I'd suggest you post the solution yourself, happy to confirm/upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just got the url all wrong, it should be http://leader.mesos:8080/